# Meaning and use of "would have to be" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage, conditionals

I'm a beginner of English and really appreciate that you can help me learn more. I noticed a sentence:

> I think all the girls in the anime are awesome, but my favorites would have to be Nozomi and Umi!

I'm really confused about the usage of *would have to be*. What's the difference between “my favorites would have to be (somebody)” and “my favorites are (somebody)”?

Comment: It's a way to not explicitly choose outright, but tell someone that, "***If you were to ask me (or if you were to make me choose) who my favorites are*** I ***would*** answer this way."

Comment: It's a form of 'hedging', just in case the person you're talking to likes Adori best. And is the person you're about to ask to lend you some money.

Comment: @Jim Please post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is an alternative to the word *"are"* but indicates that the choice is hard to make, or the chooser is reluctant to make the choice.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence indicates the conditional clause and “would have to be “ can be used in the same way as “have to be” or must be “